# Unable ot get openJPA working with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jpa, tomcat8

I'm trying to get OpenJPA working with Tomcat 8 but have been unable, it throws the error:

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The persistence provider is 
attempting to use properties in the persistence.xml file to resolve the
data source. A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name
must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or 
javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property. The following properties 
are available in the configuration: 
"org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.conf.JDBCConfigurationImpl@2655aabb".
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
        version="3.1">

...servlet stuff...

    <resource-ref>
        <description>Database</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/webservice</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

My context.xml ***(I verified this datasource works by doing a connection via InitialContext, etc in a servlet)***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Context>

    <Resource name="jdbc/webservice" auth="Container"

            type="javax.sql.DataSource"

            maxActive="8"

            removeAbandoned="true"
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
            logAbandoned="true"

            validationQuery="SELECT 1"

            username="dev" password="mypass"

            url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb"

            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver">
    </Resource>

    <Resource name="BeanManager"

            auth="Container"

            type="javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"

            factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>

</Context>
```

My persistence.xml (I also tried *every* diff combo of the properties and data-source elements. I also tried "RESOURCE_LOCAL"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
        version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="TestOpenJPAPersistence" transaction-type="JTA">

        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/webservice</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/webservice</non-jta-data-source>
<

        <properties>

            <!-- 
                I tried leaving these out, leaving them in and all combinations.
                I also tried it with the jdbc url, username, password in properties too.
            -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionDriverName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="MaxActive=10,MaxIdle=5,MinIdle=2,MaxWait=1800000"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="org.apache.openjpa.log, DefaultLevel=DEBUG, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.DynamicEnhancementAgent" value="false" />
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestWebSocket</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- Tell Maven what language version to use -->
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.enterprise/cdi-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Enables the annotations, etc needed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.exterprise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Our jersey libs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.25.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CDI to JAX-RS Binding -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish/jersey-gf-cdi-ban-custom-hk2-binding -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>2.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld.servlet/weld-servlet-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.weld/weld-core-impl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core-impl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My Servlet:

```
package com.testjpa;

import com.testpush.TestEvent;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


@WebServlet("/jpa")
public class JPAServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName = "TestOpenJPAPersistence")
    EntityManagerFactory persistenceFactory;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        EntityManager persistenceManager = null;
        String result = "Not found";
        try
        {
            //I need to do this as otherwise the factory is null
            persistenceFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "TestOpenJPAPersistence" );

            //This line throws the error
            persistenceManager = persistenceFactory.createEntityManager();
            User user = persistenceManager.find( User.class, 9 );
            if ( user != null )
            {
                result = user.getName();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( persistenceManager != null )
            {
                persistenceManager.close();
            }
        }
        resp.getWriter().println( result );
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using JTA, than you need to supply DataSource, not the Jdbc driver. Jdbc driver is only for local-transactions.

Comment: @fg78nc And how do I do that? Isn't my `<jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/webservice</jta-data-source>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/webservice</non-jta-data-source>` doing that?

Comment: Did you try to remove property for drivers?

Comment: @fg78nc yes. Still did not work

Comment: try to remove this temporily -> non-jta-data-source
Or may I suggest to use full-blown application server such as glassfish instead of just servlet-container tomcat?

Comment: @fg78nc Still didn't work

Comment: @fg78nc Unfortunately, not an option on this project

Comment: Did you try another provider EclipseLink or Hibernate?

Comment: @fg78nc I did not, but OpenJPA should work and is what I've been requested to try

Comment: Try to inject @PersistenceContext(unitName="TestOpenJPAPersistence") EntityManager em or lookup in doGet via JNDI

Comment: @fg78nc I did and that also didn't work

Comment: Upload your project (if possible) I will try to play with it

Comment: @fg78nc Thank you, I don't know where I could upload it, but the code/files are all in my question above.

Comment: Github for example. It hard to tell without trying. There are so many options.

Comment: @fg78nc Here it is: https://gitlab.com/domasija/openjpa-tomcat/blob/master/TestWebSocket.zip I'm using Tomcat 8.5.15 and Java 8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146014/discussion-between-fg78nc-and-don-rhummy).

Comment: @fg78nc Unfortunately, it didn't work. I get the error: `A Java Database Connectivity (JDBC) driver or data source class name must be specified in the openjpa.ConnectionDriverName or javax.persistence.jdbc.driver property.`

Comment: @DonRhummy : where is located your `persistence.xml` ? Looks like it's not found by the application Server. you must place it under `src/main/resources/META-INF`

Comment: @Rouliboy it's in the META-INF folder. I checked and it's there

Comment: @DonRhummy : OK. But it's obvious that `persistence.xml` is not found. If it was found, as you have both `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver` and `openjpa.ConnectionDriverName` properties, you should throw a  `ParseException`.

Comment: @DonRhummy : looking at your source, I found the problem : persistence.xml is located in `src/main/webapp/META-INF` instead of `src/main/resources/META-INF`. Move it to `src/main/resources/META-INF` and remove the `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver` property.

Comment: @Rouliboy You're a genius!! That worked! Can you please make that an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @DonRhummy : glad this helped you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your source code, I found the problem : your `persistence.xml` is located in `src/main/webapp/META-INF` instead of `src/main/resources/META-INF`.

Move it to `src/main/resources/META-INF` and remove the `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver` property and it will work.